# How to avoid chrome from doing auto Handlers

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser, desktop-application

So here is my issue. I went to a website and installed there desktop app for particular feature (screen recorder). So when i clicked on the button(for recording) in website, it asked me whether to open in desktop app. i accidentally allowed always open by checking the checkbox. but after somedays i removed the desktop app and i want to continue using the feature in web only(they support that in web as well). but now what happens whenever i click on the feature button it shows a popup saying no app associated with this in my mac os. How prevent the chrome from trying to auto open the app. I tried many ways in internet but nothing works
mac os - ventura
chrome version - 122.0.6